# pyenvを使ったPython2.7からPython3.5へバージョンアップの方法を教えていただけますか？

Tags: python, python3, python2, pyenv

独学で学習を始めた超初心者です。
Pythonをバージョンアップしたいのですが、どうしてもうまくいきません。

自分で色々調べ、pyenvを使用して Python3.5 をインストールしたのですが、切り替えがうまくいかないようです。

↓試した記事
https://qiita.com/1000ch/items/93841f76ea52551b6a97

↓試した手順
▼pyenv で Pythonをインストール`$ pyenv install 3.5.9`
▼上記記事の指示のまま`$ pyenv rehash`
▼使う Python を指定する`$ pyenv global 3.5.9`
▼以下の通り、パスが .pyenv 配下の pythonを向かない。

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

OS＝macOS Catalina

現状以下のバージョンです。

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

Python2.7.16のファイルパスは以下です。

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

pyenvのファイルパス

```
$ which pyenv
/usr/local/bin/pyenv
```

pyenvのバージョン

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
* 3.5.6 (set by /Users/yusukekurimoto/.python-version)
  3.5.7
  3.5.9
```

どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 参考にした記事を元に、あなた自身が実際に試した手順やその結果を質問文に追記してみてください。

Comment: 3.5では無さそうですが、実は元から入っていたのでは？ [macOS Catalina python 情況](https://qiita.com/mizo_cmdb/items/49abf072d93bd1d22317) `python3 が /usr/bin/に入っている` 自分で入れたいなら他にはこんな記事が参考になるかも。[OS X CatalinaでPython3系の環境設定(Homebrew+pyenv)](https://note.com/coronaupper/n/n4132bbe69bc6)

Comment: `pyenv versions`を実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: 皆さまコメントありがとうございます。
＞参考にした記事を元に、あなた自身が実際に試した手順やその結果を質問文に追記してみてください。 – cubick
→追記しました。

Comment: ＞3.5では無さそうですが、実は元から入っていたのでは？ macOS Catalina python 情況 python3 が /usr/bin/に入っている 自分で入れたいなら他にはこんな記事が参考になるかも。OS X CatalinaでPython3系の環境設定(Homebrew+pyenv) – kunif
→記事読んだのですが、ぶっちゃけ理解できませんでした、、、精進します。

Comment: ＞pyenv versionsを実行するとどうなりますか？ – letrec
→追記しました。よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 3.5.x系が必要というのなら、この記事かもしれません。[macOS catalina でpython3.5をインストールしようとしたら詰まった](https://medium.com/music-and-technology/9480751e0416)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyenv を使った場合、忘れそうなのは以下の点です。

- pyenv のパスを通す。`echo $PATH` の出力に pyenv へのパスが含まれていますか？　設定したはずなのに含まれていない場合、設定したあとシェルを再起動するなどして設定スクリプトを読み込ませましたか？
- `pyenv rehash` する。
- `pyenv global` によるシステム全体のバージョン指定か、`pyenv local` による特定のディレクトリ下でのバージョン指定を行う。特に `pyenv local` の場合は `.python-version` があるディレクトリ下でないと駄目です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
一番目：恥を承知で申し上げますと、パスの設定の仕方が不明です。調べてやってるつもりなのですが、できているのかどうか、、
二番目：これはやってました。
三番目：pyenv global これもやっていたのですが、パスが pyenv の下に向かないのです。よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: パスに関しては、参考にされていた Qiita の記事のようにシェル起動時に読み込まれるファイルにスクリプトを書くのが一般的です。

Comment: シンボリックリンクにパスを追加することによって、うまくいきました。ご丁寧な解答ありがとうございました。

Comment: @maronie 良かったです。もしよければ、自己回答としてやり方を残しておき、後からきた他の方の参考にすることもできますので、お時間ありましたらご検討ください =)

Comment: なるほど、了解しました。ご丁寧にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

シンボリックリンクにパスを追加することによって、うまくいきました。

**■手順**
▼`env`で現在のPATHをチェック
▼`sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`でpython3のファイルがあるディレクトリをシンボリックリンクに追加
▼`conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda`で3.5をインストール
▼`conda activate py35`でアクティベート

完了

みなさまありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

通りがかりですまないが、件の参考記事の「pyenv にパスを通す」は実行しただろうか？

[pyenv にパスを通す | pyenvを使ってMacにPythonの環境を構築する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/1000ch/items/93841f76ea52551b6a97#pyenv-%E3%81%AB%E3%83%91%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E9%80%9A%E3%81%99)

もし、やっているなら、次に以下のコマンドでシェルを確認してほしい。

```sh
echo $SHELL
```

macOS Catalina からはデフォルトのシェルが `zsh` になってしまったのだが、上記コマンドの結果が `bash` でないのなら、「pyenv にパスを通す」が `bash` のプロファイルに対して行われたが、`zsh` のプロファイルにないため機能していない可能性がある。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。調べたところbashでした。ずっとパスの通し方で苦戦してたのですが、シンボリックリンク変更でうまくいきました。